# how to print an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, printing

I want to print my array in php in a specific way, I hope you can help me and I thank you very much.

```
public function getLineChartPromedio($format = 'Y-m-d'){
    $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');
    $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');
    // Declare an empty array 
    $arraydias = array(); 
    
    // Variable that store the date interval 
    // of period 1 day 
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); 

    $realEnd = new DateTime($endDate); 
    $realEnd->add($interval); 

    $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($startDate), $interval, $realEnd); 
    $count = 0;
    // Use loop to store date into array 
    foreach($period as $date) {                  
        $fecha = $date->format($format);
        $arraydias [] = array ($fecha);
    } 
    
    $string = "";
    $week_array = "";
    $size = 0;
    foreach ($arraydias as $Array) {
        $string .= implode("','", $Array);
        $week_array = "'".$string."'";
    }
    echo json_encode($week_array);
    
}
```

The result of this method is: "'2020-07-082020-07-092020-07-102020-07-112020-07-12'"

What I want to achieve is: "'2020-07-08','2020-07-09','2020-07-10','2020-07-11','2020-07-12'"

What am I doing wrong? I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping much of your code. Working example:

```php
function getLineChartPromedio($format = 'Y-m-d'){
    $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');
    $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');
    // Declare an empty array 
    $arraydias = array(); 
    
    // Variable that store the date interval 
    // of period 1 day 
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); 

    $realEnd = new DateTime($endDate); 
    $realEnd->add($interval); 

    $period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($startDate), $interval, $realEnd); 
    // Use loop to store date into array 
    foreach($period as $date) {                  
        $fecha = $date->format($format);
        $arraydias[] = $fecha;
    } 
    
    $string = "'" . implode("','", $arraydias) . "'";
    echo json_encode($string);
}
```

Link to test: [click](https://3v4l.org/upeIW).

Answer (score 0):

I presume this should be enough:

```
// Use loop to store date into array 
foreach($period as $date) {                  
    $fecha = $date->format($format);
    // Note - no `array` usage here
    $arraydias [] = $fecha;
} 

echo json_encode($array_dias);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `array_map` to surround your dates with quotes, and `implode` to add commas between them:

```
echo implode(',', array_map(fn($date) => "'{$date}'", $arraydias));
```

If you need to surround this with actual double quotes:

```
echo '"', implode(',', array_map(fn($date) => "'{$date}'", $arraydias)), '"';
```

This implies you initially added dates to your array normally earlier:

```
$arraydias[] = $fecha;
```

(as opposed to `$arraydias [] = array($fecha);` like you did)